# POST data, Sessions and other forms transmitted to another website

Tags: php, magento, http-post

I am an affiliate of an online store, and I promote it through my own website which is targeted for a specific language.

One of the issues i'm having with my affiliated site, is that he would not translate his website to the language I am promoting it in. Meaning, when I redirect to his website with my referral code, the visitor is suddenly seeing English text as the affiliated site is not supporting the visitor's language.

I thought I would replicate his entire website (Magento based) and translating it all.

But the problem is that I don't and can't handle the actual payment processing, so I need to transfer all POST data, Session info and everything relevant to the action script on the affiliated website without showing it to the visitor.

Is that possible? Can anyone think of a better way to accomplish what i'm trying to do here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't be a particularly simple project, but it's possible. You would need to create a payment method that forwards to the other site, basically what Paypal does. You'll need cooperation from the other site owner to have him allow you to send all the cart / user data at once.

If the other site owner offers an API to his site, that would be a good route to go down as well.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe